# Twiml Connect method issue

Tags: node.js, twilio

So i'm trying to make it so an outbound call gets redirected to my Autopilot system, but my Twiml does seem to recognize the connect function built into the voice response method

I've tried to have the account sid be provided, call, and even load the link in a browser, it just gives the same error

Heres the code im using

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let res = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    console.log(res.toString());
    res.connect().autopilot(context.AI_SID);
    console.log(res.toString());
    callback(null, res);
};
```

It should return the code below, but seems like this doc is not accurate: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect

```
<Response>
  <Connect>
    <Autopilot>#####</Autopilot>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Twilio helper libraries under your Twilio Functions, Configure, to use a release that added this verb.

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Oh, perfect, thank you! I was using verion 3.6.3, the default version when u open an account, i've been way out of date. Thank you very much :)